# Print job working on virtual machine but not in outside workspace

Tags: printing, powerbuilder, printers

Good day.

So basically the problem is that there is a print job request from a PowerBuilder Application. It works when it is triggered inside the virtual machine and it fails when triggered on the main OS. My questions is how does a virtual machine handle print requests? This is really weird. I can't helped but think that if there is a thing that shall fail regarding printer, It will be the one triggered inside the VM and not the main OS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Powerbuilder is always executing through a virtual machine. Do you mean  there is a different behavior in printing between a session from the IDE and when started directly from the application .exe?

Comment: or do you mean you are executing your PB application in a VirtualBox / VritualPC / VMWare and that the result is different from your develeopment box?

Comment: What *specific* function is failing? "Print job" could mean any number of functions. Troubleshooting PrintOpen() is vastly different than dw.Print(). (My guess is that the relation between failure and VM is coincidental, maybe related, but not causal.)

Comment: hi guys. Yes I only have a .exe of the PB application. I tried to used it a VMWare virtual machine and an outside OS. Anyway, My problem is already solved. It turned out I need to install a PB runtime to be able to use the app normally. Thanks for all the help!